# Server take long time to response and I get the connection has timed out message from my browser after runnig

Tags: c#

I want to write a program that pass text(message) from one Ip address to another in a workgroup.I have send and receive button In this program,The send is ok but when i click receive,At the first line of try block, Server takes long time to response and I get the connection has timed out message from my browser after runnig.
textbox1 is sender ipaddress.
textbox2 is receiver ipaddress.
My code is:

```
 Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

protected void receive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ip = TextBox2.Text;
    IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipa, 1029);
    socket.Connect(endPoint);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    // length of the text "Hello world!"
    try
    {
        int iRx= socket.Receive(buffer);
        TextBox4.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /* ... */ }
}
protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ip =TextBox1.Text ;
    IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipa, 1029);
    socket.Connect(endPoint);
    try
    {
        string str = "Hello word";
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        socket.Send(byData);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a PHP app that I built.  What was happening was - the browser will wait for a certain minimum amount of data to be received before doing... anything.  If it doesn't see much communication, it will just timeout.  How I solved the problem, I filled the buffer with spaces (" ") using a for loop - then flushed the buffer - which told the browser to send the data it had received.  I would try forcing the browser to act... because they dont like to on their own.

Comment: can you send your code to me? I understand your mean but I need help yet

Comment: Well its going to be a lot different because I did it in PHP and used the ob_flush() function and end_all_flush() function etc etc... but I can look into how to mirror that with csharp.... unless you want the PHP code just to see what was going on...

Comment: I added a for block after buffer defination and filled the buffer with 0.where should i flush the buffer?

Comment: Well... its hard to say - i would need to test / look around more But I would try something like:
1) Set up your buffer
2) Fill it with nonsense
3) Fill buffer with message
4) flush()
5) try to receive message